# Django loaddata from fixture returns error

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite, django-models

Hello there i'm trying to move my django project from SQLite to PostgreSQL and in order to do that i need to populate the DB with some initial values. I already have 4 different fixture files with the initial data. These files are inside a fixtures directory inside the app. One per model and one including all initial data that i currently have on my SQLite DB.

I already Created the DB in PostgreSQL and made the proper changes to the `settings.py` file in order to move to the PostgreSQL DB.

The problem is that when i use `python manage.py loaddata InitialData` command it returns an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/seba94/.local/share/virtualenvs/register-page-jYLn8mRO/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "reg_producto" does not exist
LINE 1: ...eg_producto"."Name", "reg_producto"."CMS_id" FROM "reg_produ...
                                                             ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/seba94/.local/share/virtualenvs/register-page-jYLn8mRO/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/seba94/.local/share/virtualenvs/register-page-jYLn8mRO/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/seba94/.local/share/virtualenvs/register-page-jYLn8mRO/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/seba94/.local/share/virtualenvs/register-page-jYLn8mRO/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/seba94/.local/share/virtualenvs/register-page-jYLn8mRO/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/home/seba94/.local/share/virtualenvs/register-page-jYLn8mRO/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/seba94/register-page/register_page/reg/models.py", line 61, in <module>
    class Preaprobado(models.Model):
  File "/home/seba94/register-page/register_page/reg/models.py", line 66, in Preaprobado
    productos = models.ManyToManyField(Producto, related_name = "preaprobados", default = Producto.objects.get(CMS_id = 1))
  File "/home/seba94/.local/share/virtualenvs/register-page-jYLn8mRO/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/seba94/.local/share/virtualenvs/register-page-jYLn8mRO/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 402, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/home/seba94/.local/share/virtualenvs/register-page-jYLn8mRO/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 256, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/seba94/.local/share/virtualenvs/register-page-jYLn8mRO/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1242, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/seba94/.local/share/virtualenvs/register-page-jYLn8mRO/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 55, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/home/seba94/.local/share/virtualenvs/register-page-jYLn8mRO/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1100, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/seba94/.local/share/virtualenvs/register-page-jYLn8mRO/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/seba94/.local/share/virtualenvs/register-page-jYLn8mRO/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/seba94/.local/share/virtualenvs/register-page-jYLn8mRO/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/seba94/.local/share/virtualenvs/register-page-jYLn8mRO/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/seba94/.local/share/virtualenvs/register-page-jYLn8mRO/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/seba94/.local/share/virtualenvs/register-page-jYLn8mRO/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "reg_producto" does not exist
LINE 1: ...eg_producto"."Name", "reg_producto"."CMS_id" FROM "reg_produ...
```

My guess is that due to some model relations this error ocurrs. I did some research in the [loaddata docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.2/ref/django-admin/#loaddata) and i saw that making some changes with the handlers of the related fields there should be a solution. Since it's my first time working with django i honestly don't know where should i apply this code in order to solve the problem.

Comment: Did you run the migrations after creating and switching to the new db? It looks like the tables are not created.

Comment: makemigrations command returns the same error log. I guess that there is a problem with the need of populating the DB first. Since there are some default values in the models that depend on other models being created first

Comment: as far as I know, migrate will create your database structure

Comment: i'm following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04) tutorial but instead of creating a new django project i'm cloning from git the one i have in my test enviroment. Every command i run from manage.py related to database returns the same error log

Comment: Finally was able to migrate following the django docs solution that is suggested when having related models